# How to set the root name of Apache IoTDB that has number sets in it?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I have a question when I am reading official guide of Apache IoTDB. The document says: In Version 1.0, identifiers quoted without backticks are not allowed to be real numbers, and are only allowed to contain letters, characters, and underscores. I wonder if there is a root name called `root.SG001.12345678910.TEST DEVICE`, is this device name illegal?

For the number part, do I need to add backticks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to add backticks to this root name in Apache IoTDB. However, only the continuous number part needs to add backticks, so the legal name will be like: "root.SG001.`12345678910`.TEST DEVICE".